# Magento 2: Get collection in specific order

Tags: magento2, collection, products

I want to get collection in specific order (apart from ASC or DESC order).

Here is my collection:

```
$productCollection = $block->getProductCollection()
->create()
->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',array('in' => array_keys($products_in_orders)))
->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $category_ids])
->load();
```

And I want to get collection in exactly `array_keys($products_in_orders)` this order which is an array of entity_id (e.g. 18,15,16,20)

Here is the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185029/sort-by-order-of-values-in-a-select-statement-in-clause-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code.

```
$productIds=array(18,15,16,20);
$productCollection = $block->getProductCollection()
                ->create()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
                ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',array('in' => array_keys($products_in_orders)))
                ->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $category_ids]);
$productCollection->getSelect()->order(new \Zend_Db_Expr('FIELD(entity_id,' . implode(',', $productIds).')'));
$productCollection->load();
```

I didn't test it, but it should work.